# WebService Client in Java with jax-rpc

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, jax-rpc

I need to use jax-rpc in a project using the Eclipse IDE. The problem is that I don't know what JDK to use because when I write:

```
import javax.xml.rpc;
```

or

```
import javax.xml.rpc.Stub;
```

I get an error error telling me Eclipse IDE can not find it in the library.

I downloaded the JDK 7 and JDK 6, but neither solves it.

There is a Jax-ws library but, I know I need to use jax-rpc.

Comment: That does not look like a valid import statement. What does the `o` mean? Did you mean *or*?

Comment: Yes i want to say or.

Comment: Note that you can click [edit] below your question to update. (I did the edit for you this time :)

Comment: have a look http://java2practice.com/2014/03/01/java-rpc-style-webservice-with-jax-ws/

Comment: You should be able to do whatever you are trying to do with jax-ws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open www.google.com

write "download javax.xml.rpc library"

download jar file.

Place the jar file in plugin folder of eclipse.

Right click on your java project->Build path->Add library-> browse the jar from plugin folder.

Comment: Thank you! 

Do you know any place where i can find a tutorial for web services jax-rpc con eclipse ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you didnt add the library in the project.  please add rpc jar in the project.  RPC is older version of webservice for the tutorial you cans use http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC3.html.  You can also use apache axis which more better than the rpc style of webservice.